# AppCenter results in TesPlan. Azure Devops

Tags: azure, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

Currently, I am writing tests using Xamarin.UI.Test framework. The tests are running in AppCenter.
I have a problem. I want to run my automated tests from the Test Plan level in Azure DevOps.
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops)

Am I able to do that using AppCenter?
I know that I have to create a release pipeline and use a [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops).
But when I am using VS test task I need to connect directly to the emulator? Am I right?
Maybe I can do that other way using AppCenter.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some workaround. And I've found a similar solution. I've created Test Plan and Test Suite named "Regression". I've put all my test cases into this test suite. And what I am doing here. I've associated test cases with my methods. [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops)
And I prepared python script which is responsible for updating Test Outcome in my regression suite via Azure Devops REST API ([using this enpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test-point/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)). Basically my script consumes test result XML file from App Center, maps results from file to corresponding Test Case and updates test outcome via REST API.

Comment: This is useful guidance. But it would be even more useful if you expanded it with some sample code. It doesn't need to be your complete code, and especially if it contains proprietary details. But it should give readers enough to get started. Can you edit your answer to include some sample code?